# why is my program code not running goto statement infinitely in c#?

Tags: c#-4.0, goto

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
       int i ;
        for ( i=0; i < 10;i++ )
        {
       // p: Console.WriteLine("hello");
        p:  if(i%2!=0)
            {
                if(i==5)
                { 
                    goto p; 
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

`//output : 0 1 2 3 4`

Comment: `i%2` calculates the remainder. In order to fulfill the condition `i%2` to be `0`, the number `i` must be even. So `i must be` 0, 2, 4, 6 or 8`, none of which is `5`.

Answer (score 0):

The `goto` is being executed. Unfortunately, nothing has changed in the variables so that execution takes the exact same path as before: It reaches the `goto` again. This is an infinite loop.

Note, that in particular `i` has the same value before and after the jump. Maybe this is your misunderstanding.

You should learn to use the debugger. You can see this when single-stepping through the program.